# How generate phpDoc html from PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

I've not found how generate html format for phpDoc from PhpStorm IDE.

Or should I only use console for this this task, e.g. like this:

```
$ phpdoc -d|-f <PATH> -t <PATH> [parameters]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. PhpStorm does not have built-in support for PHPDoc or any other doc system (ApiDoc, Doxygen etc) in terms of generating final documentation files.
2. PhpStorm has [External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) functionality exactly for such situations.
3. Or you can use any build system (e.g. [Phing](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Phing+Support+in+PhpStorm) based on Ant / [Gulp](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/11/gulp-in-webstorm-9/) / [Grunt](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/05/grunt-in-webstorm-8/) (both require Node.js) or alike) and create such task there (PhpStorm supports all 3 of them).

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/creating-php-documentation-comments.html?origin=old_help
what is this ?

Comment: @LeoKomarov It's about creating and using PHPDoc comments in actual PhpStorm to document your code. PhpStorm uses PHPDoc exactly for this purpose -- describing to IDE what function/class/etc does, what parameters is has, what types etc. IDE even uses PHPDoc style comments for internal purposes (e.g. warning suppression etc). It still has nothing to do with final html generation.